# Array Ilteration Ruby

Tags: ruby

A problem asks to print all numbers from an array that are greater than 100. When I run this:

```
array = [3, 123, 433, -77, 56, 200, 99, 101, 6]

index = 0
9.times do
  if array[index] > 100 == 0
    p array[index]
  end
  index = index + 1
end
```

the number 9 is printed. I put in the proper conditional if the number was greater than 100 to get printer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post the text, not a screenshot image.

Comment: `9` is the outcome of `9.times`, this method returned `9` and hence you see it.

Comment: Use `each` with a conditional `array.each { |n| condition on n }`

Comment: @SagarPandya `puts array.select(&100.method(:<=))`

Comment: I don't see how this code could possibly print `9`. The only operation that prints something is the `puts` and that is unreachable code.

Answer (score 3):

Your program doesn't print any of the array values because of that condition

```
if array[index] > 100 == 0
```

it should be just

```
if array[index] > 100
```

don't know why you add that `== 0`

`array[index] > 100` is evaluted before so all the time you always obtain `true == 0` or `false == 0`, and these are never true. So no prints in your code

about that 9 that come up it's what Aleksei says

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot to take it off since it's not looking for any numbers that are % by anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
if array[index] > 100
  # print
end
```

9 is the evaluation of your program, it's not a 'print', it's the result of `9.times`

Answer (score 3):

The problem's actually really easy to solve if you know the right tools to use:

```
array = [3,123,433,-77,56,200,99,101,6]

array.select { |n| n > 100 }.each do |n|
  puts n
end
```

Where [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-select) can help narrow down lists of numbers. Ruby's Array class has an unusually large number of methods like this that can quickly and easily do a variety of things related to filtering and mapping.

The `9.times` part in your code was decoupled from the actual length of the array, something that leads to a whole lot of bugs if you add/remove entries and these two fall out of sync.

Use array iterators whenever possible, like:

```
array = [3,123,433,-77,56,200,99,101,6]

array.each do |n|
  if (n > 100)
    puts n
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have written `9.times` which is your array size, which indicates you want to run it for all array elements. So use **each** block on array.

```
array.each { |x| puts x if x > 100 }
```

Try to understand why there is no role of `index` of any array element in above.

Answer (score 0):

Select returns its own array. So we can just print the return value.

```
puts array.select{|x| x > 99}
```